# What can be the resolution of Query timeout expired issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bids, script-task

I am facing an issue while running SSIS package using Microsoft Visual Studio

Thing is, this issue does not occur all of time.

The error message:

> Error: Query timeout expired

N.B: The error occurs in a script task, my guess is, there is a setting where it limits the run time and through errors when it exceeds.

Any suggestion to resolve this scenario is very much appreciated

Comment: You need to provide more details, what is the script task code? why you are assuming that it is thrown from script task?

Comment: What is your script task doing? Are you calling a web service?

Comment: The first suggestion I have to resolve this issue is for you to provide some details so we have a chance at solving the real issue. At this point we are left to randomly speculate why this happens.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @TabAlleman the OP didn't logged in after he asked the question. I think that it is good to give him a chance to edit the question.

Comment: That's fine, but https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98026/272049

Comment: - I am not assuming.It is showing error on the script task.

Comment: In the scrip task, there is simple if else logic which set a variable upon checking some files exists or not in folder path.

Comment: Also, I am using Database connection and Sql Command in it

Comment: @BlackCat, you need to post more details about what your script task is doing.  First you say it's checking to see if files exist, then you say you're using a Database connection and SQL Command.  Our ability to help you varies directly with how much information you provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the timeout on your SQL Command in the script task.